# Out of memory error on using group faceting

Tags: solr, grouping, facet

I've an index of 40M documents and machine configuration is 72 cores, 500GB RAM & NVME drives.

I am using JSON faceting on multivalued field and it is working fine irrespective of the number of documents matching. But, if i am applying group faceting using unique function, it is throwing out of memory error and bringing my solr down (when number of documents matching is > 500k).

I am using the following syntax for group faceting.

```
json.facet={
   categories:{
     type : terms,
     field : cat,
     sort : { x : desc},
     facet:{
       x : "unique(type)"     
    }
   }
 }
```

Following is the sample schema that i am using

```
<schema>
    <types>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"  />

        <fieldType name="lower_string" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
        </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
    </types>

    <fields>
        <field name="cat"  type="lower_string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"  />
        <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" docValues="true" />
    </fields>

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Any idea how can we resolve this?

Comment: What are the field types of cat and type?

Comment: @MatsLindh: cat is **text** field and type is **string** field

Comment: Please include the _complete_ definition of the fields, the schema version and the Solr version - it's relevant to how faceting is done. And TextFields can't use docValues IIRC, and docValues are usually the solution for excessive memory usage.

Comment: @MatsLindh: I've updated my question with schema.

Comment: Try using a separate field for the category, define the field as string, and do the processing before indexing the content into the field. Use that for faceting instead, and be sure to enable docValues for the field type. The RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory shouldn't be necessary for a KeywordTokenized field with only a lowercasefilter before it either.

Answer (score -1):

Solr json-facet performance on string type field is poor with initial relase version of json-facet API. JSON-facet api performs well on int/long/double fields.

Please go through this solr mailing list discussion if it helps!

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/JSON-facet-performance-for-aggregations-td4332617.html

Comment: I know this however, i am using latest solr version i.e 7.4 and expecting this should not be a problem. Even if that is the problem, performance should be bad but here it is taking complete memory and i am not sure why memory should be effected.